# Como cargar en mis input información después de ingresar en otros input sin necesidad de un evento Click?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Tengo un un formulario que tiene que registrar información en unos input, y que al darse el evento onChange de estos input en otros input cargue información. Ejemplo:

```
input type="number" onChange={this.handleNumeroA} value={this.state.numeroA} 
input type="number" onChange={this.handleNumeroB} value={this.state.numeroB} 

input type="number" readOnly onChange={this.resultado} value={this.state.resultado}
```

En los eventos handleNumeroA y handleNumeroB deben recibir con e.target.value los números que se registren por el usuario. Pero al terminar debe presentar el resultado por decir de la suma de estos 2 números.

Como se puede resolver?
Tal vez haciendo que el evento de handleNumeroB tenga el action que haga el setState del estado resultado??

He leído por ejemplo sobre los métodos React.component que podría ayudar componentDidUpdate pero no tengo claro como se usa.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacer el ejemplo de la suma, solo es necesario guardar en el `state` los valores de `NumeroA` y `NumeroB`, y en cada uno poner el mismo handler:

```
constructor(){
  // En el estado solo ponemos las variables necesarias:
  this.state = { A: 0, B: 0 };

  // Aseguramos el handler para los eventos onChange:
  this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

// Escribimos este método genérico para controlar los cambios en cualquier input:
handleInputChange(e){
  const target = e.target;
  const name = target.name;
  const value = target.value;
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
}

render(){
  // La suma no necesita ser parte del estado, la podemos definir aquí:
  let suma = parseInt(this.state.A) + parseInt(this.state.B);
  return(
    <form>
      <label htmlFor="NumA">Número A:</label>
      <input name="A" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.A} id="NumA" />
      <label htmlFor="NumB">Número B:</label>
      <input name="B" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.B} id="NumB" />
      <label htmlFor="NumSum">SUMA:</label>
      <input value={suma} id="NumSum" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Te recomiendo leer:

- [Errores comunes en React.js: estado innecesario (en inglés)](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/09/common-react-dot-js-mistakes-unneeded-state/)

---

Respecto a `ComponentDidUpdate` y símiles, estás entrando a otro terreno.

**[ComponentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)** es parte del [ciclo de vida de los componentes](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) de React, el cual básicamente funciona así:

#### Montaje

1. Se llama al [`constructor`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) del componente, donde se inicializa el `state`.
2. Antes de montar el elemento se llama a [`ComponentWillmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) (antes del primer `render`). Nada importante a destacar aquí; de hecho en la documentación dice:

   > Evita introducir cualquier acción de efectos secundarios o suscripciones (**Ajax para los cuates**) en este método. Para esos casos, use `ComponentDidMount` en su lugar.
   >   .
3. Se ejecuta el primer [`render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) que pintará el elemento en pantalla.
4. Si es necesario obtener información desde el servidor (Ajax), se ejecuta [`ComponentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). Aquí puedes cambiar el estado inicial.

Una vez montado el elemento, *puede* comenzar el ciclo de

#### Actualización

1. [`ComponentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) será invocado si las `props` del elemento cambian.

   > Si necesitas actualizar el estado en respuesta a cambios en los `props` (por ejemplo, para resetearlo), debes comparar `this.props` y `nextProps` y ejecutar las transiciones de estado usando `this.setState()` en este método.
2. Para validar si el cambio de estado afectará la interfaz, puedes utilizar [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) que debe devolver `true` o `false` indicando si el elemento debe volver a invocar a `render` o no.
3. Si no usamos el método anterior, o si retornó `true`, pasamos a [`ComponentWillUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate). Nada destacable aquí, solo que **no debes invocar a this.setState aquí**.
4. Se ejecuta nuevamente el `render` con los cambios aplicados.
5. Puedes ejecutar cualquier validación extra después del renderizado en [`ComponentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). Nada destacable aquí tampoco, pero puede servirte si combinas React con jQuery.

Si necesitas hacer algo antes de que el elemento sea destruido, puedes utilizar [`ComponentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) y también tienes [`ComponentDidCatch`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch) para control de errores.